Cartridge style bottom bracket temperature range
I'm hoping to continue riding through winter in a place where it regularly gets down to -20°F (around -29°C). I've seen some threads about replacing the wheel hub grease, and freehub oil with something that works at lower temperatures. However, I haven't been able to find any information on operating temperatures for sealed bottom brackets (e.g. UN-300).
Does any information exist about this? Has anyone run into problems with the bottom bracket seizing up in low temperatures? And is there any way to mitigate the effects of low temperatures on a sealed cartridge bottom bracket?

Not sure if this counts as a full answer, but from seeing your profile bio, any chance you have access to a lab-grade freezer that you could put a BB in? Then you could easily check to see how much the grease thickens. But anyways, considering the global ubiquity of bicycles, surely a lot of people would be having problems with frozen grease, so my intuition is that it's not a huge concern. Perhaps it's not great for racing purposes in terms of increased power loss, but a sane person wouldn't be bike racing in that weather...

Unfortunately (or fortunately) I am a theorist, and so I don't have access to such a freezer. I suppose I could put it in my home freezer to see if it becomes any more sluggish, but I probably couldn't get down to -20F. To your point about global ubiquity, I had suspected that most normal people just put the bicycle away for the winter, or are willing to do some kind of special maintenance. From EyeBrown's remarks, it seems like that's not the case.

Kind of a known issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uak8TG6Z9-w

If you look at the datasheets for bike greases or industrial bearings they usually have at least -20°C to 100°C temperature range.

@Michael That is precisely the issue in the question, -20°F is around -30°C, so it is outside the range that the manufacturers specify as safe usage range.

@quarague: But it looks like the range for greases often extends down to -30°C. I wouldn’t expect anything bad to suddenly happen at low temperatures. I guess at high temperatures you could get to a point where the grease becomes liquid enough to simply flow out of the bearing.

The operating range depends on excactly what it is made of, which is almost impossible to find out for these units. Either way, even if -30C is below op.temp. it will most likely just perform suboptimally, be a bit more sluggish and cause increased wear. These units wear out anyway, and who needs to ride at 30km/h at -30C? If it freezes solid, let us know. Seems few people ride at -30C, -15C is my limit.

I also live in Minneapolis. Your bottom bracket will be just fine. As you'll soon notice plenty of people in the city ride year round and approximately 0 percent of them selected their bottom brackets on any basis other than "it fits" and the price.

Also even in Minneapolis, saying it gets down to -20F "regularly" is stretching it, most winters it doesnt get that cold at all, and winters it does, it's usually just one or two days and thats it. -10F is much more "regular" and still only maybe 10-20 days of the winter, tops.

Fair enough on the temperature correction. I've got the polar vortex from a few years back on the mind when it got down to -50F wind chill. Though, probably ill-advised to be riding in those conditions.

In short: I’ve never had any (significant) problems and I wound’t worry unless I’d really notice some issues.
Where I live (Eastern Finland), temperatures below –25 °C (–13 °F) are not exceptional, and below –30 °C (–22 °F) can happen for few days a winter (last winter we had a week where it stayed consistently below –28 °C). I commute daily with my bike, I’ve never changed any bearing or freehub grease to anything “winter specific” and I never had any bearings to seize up. Nowadays I keep my bikes in a garage where the temperature stays above freezing, but at work I have to leave my bikes outdoors and after ~10 h, there hasn’t been any issues.
In cold temperatures grease gets more viscous. You might notice this as the bike feeling more sluggish. When I was young, I kept my bike in unheated shelter, and on those –30 °C mornings, biking to school was extra annoying as everything felt harder. But I attribute that more to the thick layer of gunk that was covering my chain than any issues with bottom brackets (back then the prevalent chain oiling paradigm was “more is better”). And even the slightly more viscous grease loosens up as you start to pedal. Unlike the bikes, I keep my car outdoors (garage is full of bikes) and after being unused for few days in –25 °C, it’s clear that all oils and greases are more stiff (to the extend that I sometimes have to keep the clutch open for a minute or so to heat the engine a bit as otherwise the extra resistance from the transmission grease, even when on neutral, kills the engine).
The few cases I’ve seen anything on a bike to seize up because of freezing temperatures have all involved water. If you have water in your bottom bracket bearings, they will seize up (already in mildly freezing conditions). I’ve had my front derailleur cable froze (or rather, I’ve had water inside the cable housing that froze and seized the cable). And so on. But this is more a matter of ordinary bike maintenance and I always give my bikes a good overhaul before winter to make sure all parts are in a good condition and water has minimal changes to get in. Overall, I think the hardest situations for bikes in winter are when the temperature drops suddenly from above-freezing to really cold (say, below –15 °C).
Having said all that, it is possible that where you live the winters have properties that are unlike where I live and I’ve overlooked them. So talking with locals with experience is definitely a good idea.

+1. I’ve cycled in -18°C weather with normal Shimano Hollowtech bearings and didn’t notice any unusual resistance. Similar to you, my only temperature-related issues in winter have been frozen rear derailleurs and snow/ice built-up on the cassette and rims.

This is a very interesting question. I'm not personally equipped to handle it, and I'm not sure how many of us here are equipped to do so.
The Iditabike is the bike version of the Iditarod. Technically, the Iditarod Trail Invitational seems to cover fat bikes, foot, and skis. It is through Alaska and it is very cold. A Google search for "Iditabike +grease" might be fruitful. One of the results was this page on Bikepacking.com, which covered a lot of participant bikes. A few of the entries mention packing all bearings with arctic or low-temperature grease.
They didn't specifically say anything about their BBs, and in general it's annoying to remove the bearings from either cartridge BBs or press-fit BBs. Additionally, especially if the cartridge bearings have full-contact seals, removing the seal to change the grease might damage the seal. Anyway, some BB units have bearings that can be accessed, so if you want to change the grease, it might be helpful to know what BB you currently have.
From here, you might continue to refine the search parameters, or try to reach some of the individual athletes on their social media to ask them. If you get a response, feel free to post it here!

This answer has some interesting info, and I may reach out to some of the folks listed in the article -- a few are local! I'm aware that loose bearing/cup & cone bottom brackets exist, and I imagine using low-temperature grease with that setup would work. However, I'm asking specifically about BBs where you can't access the grease, given that new cup + cone BBs are expensive and somewhat cumbersome to service.

I've used the UN300 down to -15C without noticing any issues from the BB. Instead my chain often get stiff links after being covered in salty slush and left outside for a few hours.
Some sites list calcium greases to have an operating temp down to -20C (1), others go further. I'm not sure what grease shimano uses in BBs, but one site lists shimano premium grease as a mixture of "Molybdenum Disulfide, Calcium Sulfonate, Lithium" (2).
I do store my bike at room temperature in general, and shimano does recommend storing their premium grease above 0C (3).
I have had some calcium grease stored outside for 10 years+ through -20C winters with no obvious macroscopic degradation. I'm currently using this old stuff in the front hub, works great.
My belief is that the reduced lubrication from too cold grease is less important than the influx of dirt/grit or salty slush for this BB. Ideally you would store the bike above 0C as Shimano at least reccomends for their "premium grease". But if they use a proper grease (like my ca-grease), leaving it outside with lows down to -20C through winter should be no major problem. Rides at -15C and leaving it outside afterwards for 4-5 hours 2-3 times a week has worked out for me, but I have not gone beyond 5000km on this BB with this kind of use included.
(1) https://www.lubechemconsultant.com/calcium-grease
(2) https://www.amazon.co.uk/SHIMANO-Premium-Grease-Tube-100/dp/B001XE15WO
(3) https://hollandbikeshop.com/pdf_hazards/shimano-grease-dura-ace-pot-500gr-302367.pdf

Shimano's premium grease is rebranded Motorex Bike Grease 2000. The listed temperature range is down to -30°C. However I don't believe this is the grease actually used in the BBs.

@MaplePanda Might be true, how do you know this to be true? I have no idea what they use in their BBs. Which is partly why it is hard to give a good answer. The other part is that few people ride bikes in -30C. Anyway, I think they use their premium grease in hubs from the looks of it. It's a bit too thin IMO, which is why I chose to replace it.
